# Replace printed char of an array

Tags: c

I would like to print the following array, then replace the I's with * from left to right with a one second pause between each print.

```
main()
{
  char arr1[6] = {'T', 'T', 'I', 'T', 'T', 'T'};
  char arr2[6] = {'T', 'T', 'I', 'I','I','T'};
  char arr3[6] = {'T', 'T', 'T', 'T','I','T'};
  char loop;
  char loop2;
  char loop3;
  for(loop = 0; loop < 6; loop++)
     printf("%c", arr1[loop]);
     printf("\n");

    
   
  for(loop2 = 0; loop2 < 6; loop2++)
     printf("%c", arr2[loop2]);
     printf("\n");
     


  for(loop3 = 0; loop3 < 6; loop3++)
     printf("%c", arr3[loop3]);
     printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Current Output:

```
    TTITTT
    TTIIIT
    TTTTIT
```

I want the I's to be replace with * with a one second pause between the following print statements.

Desired 1:

```
    TT*TTT
    TTIIIT
    TTTTIT
```

(one second delay)...
Desired 2:

```
    TT*TTT
    TT*IIT
    TTTTIT
```

(one second delay)
Desired 3:

```
    TT*TTT
    TT**IT
    TTTTIT
```

etc....

Therefore, I would like the final output to be:

```
    TT*TTT
    TT***T
    TTTT*T
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Which part do you have problems with?

Comment: I want to replace the I's with * after it prints I. I will make an edit for clearer understanding! :)

Comment: I understand what you want to do. But you need to explain what prevents you from doing it. Do you not now how to iterate the array? Do you not know how to sleep? Do you not know the algorithm? That is, ask a specific question rather than just say what the program needs to do.

Comment: Tip: Put your iterator variables in the iterators themselves, as in `for (int i = 0; ...)` not pre-declaring these, especially not in a giant heap. You don't need *N* of these, you need one you use over and over. By tradition `i` is used.

Comment: Tip: **Write functions** to do something, then call that function *N* times. Don't just paste in sort of the same code *N* times.

Comment: Hint: Write a loop. Write a function that substitutes one at a time and returns how many it changed. Write a function to display the structure. Use `sleep()`. Make the loop terminate when it runs out of things to change.

Comment: kaylum, I do not understand how to iterate the array and I do not understand the proper algorithm and I do not understand the code to replace char T with *.

Comment: @Brendan to address someone you must use `@` like what I'm using so the person receives a notification